# Powershell list all methods named 'Create'

Tags: powershell, syntax

I am trying to filter all methods named 'Create' in all workspaces as part of a learning Powershell exercise.

I have this command which seems to list all the methods but I am unable to filter on 'Create' when I pipe the output of teh below to either `-Filter` or `where`.

What am I doing wrong here?

`Get-WmiObject * -List | Where-Object {$_.methods} | select -ExpandProperty Methods`

With `-Filter`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WmiObject * -List | Where-Object {$_.methods} | select -ExpandProperty Methods | -Filter
-Filter : The term '-Filter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:86
+ ...  Where-Object {$_.methods} | select -ExpandProperty Methods | -Filter
+                                                                   ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Filter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Or `select where`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WmiObject * -List | Where-Object {$_.methods} | select -ExpandProperty Methods | select name
 -eq "Create"
Select-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'eq'.
At line:1 char:98
+ ... _.methods} | select -ExpandProperty Methods | select name -eq "Create ...
+                                                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

Comment: `gwmi * -List | ? Methods | select -Exp Methods| ? Name -eq 'Create'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list the actual `Create` *methods themselves*:

```
Get-WmiObject -List |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Methods |
    Where-Object Name -eq Create
```

If, by contrast, you want to list the *classes* that have a `Create` method:

```
Get-WmiObject -List | Where-Object { $_.Methods.Name -contains 'Create' }
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `-Filter` is a *parameter*, yet you tried to use it as a *command*. It's also unclear *what* you're trying to filter, given that there's no argument.
- `select name -eq "Create"` mistakenly applies the `Where-Object` syntax to the `Select-Object` (`select`) cmdlet.

In both attempts:

- the use of `Where-Object {$_.methods}` is unnecessary, because the
  `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Methods` call will automatically ignore method-less classes.
- `-List` by itself is enough to list all classes; no need for wildcard `*`.